# No validation working on the form inside the jQuery UI dialog

Tags: forms, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

No validation plugin is working on the form contained inside a jquery Ui dialog box. Using Bassistance jQuery validation plugin, works great out of the ui modal box, no luck working it on the form contained inside the jQuery Ui modal box, nor the [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) method is working. What might be wrong? Almost pulling hair out for this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was not a jquery or any js problem.

The html was not formated properly, the form element was "inside" a table which didnot work,
always have form element enclose a table

```
<form>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td><!--input element here--></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and **not**

```
<table>
    <form>
      <tr>
          <td><!--input element here--></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

If you are enclosing form inside a table cell, it should be ok.